# SQL How to parse text value(VARCHAR) and then get milliseconds value?

Tags: sql

There are varchar column may contain this examples (only 3 variants of values):
  Oct 15, 2013  |
  15/10/2013    |
  2013-10-15
Need to update column values and set the appropriate values for milliseconds: 1381723200000. Without changing type column.

Comment: What is your database?  And what do you mean by "update column" and "get milliseconds"?  Your examples are all dates, no milliseconds anywhere.

Comment: What is your DB and current column definition?

Comment: @Andrew what milliseconds he mean is, convert date to its equivalent millisecond value. In java CurrentMilliSecond means `the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.`

Comment: Most DBMS have handy builtin functions to parse dates from strings and to calculate Unix timestamps from dates. You haven't mentioned any DBMS so—do you really want a cross-platform standard SQL solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Perspective:**

If you want to extract Milliseconds from a string with YYYY-DD-MM format or whatever (without milliseconds)

```
SELECT
     TO_CHAR( TO_TIMESTAMP ( '2013-10-15',
                  'YYYY-MM-DD' ),'FF9')
FROM
      DUAL;
```

will give you 000000000 always in Oracle, since there is no milliseconds value stored in your string.

But, if you want to convert the date into milliseconds, then

Milliseconds since when???

```
SELECT
     ( TO_DATE ( '2013-10-16', 
              'YYYY-MM-DD' ) -- starting date
      - TO_DATE ( '2013-10-15',
              'YYYY-MM-DD' )) -- ending date
              *24*60*60*1000 -- milliseconds multiplication factor
FROM
      DUAL;
```